# Simple way to implement a Collection?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, yield, ienumerator

I am developing a collection class, which should implement IEnumerator and IEnumerable.

In my first approach, I implemented them directly. Now I have discovered the yield keyword, and I have been able to simplify everything a whole lot substituting the IEnumerator/IEnumerable interfaces with a readonly property Values that uses yield to return an IEnumerable in a loop.

My question: is it possible to use yield in such a way that I could iterate over the class itself, without implementing IEnumerable/IEnumerator?

I.e., I want to have a functionality similar to the framework collections:

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
foreach (int i in myList)
{
    ...
}
```

Is this possible at all?

**Update:** It seems that my question was badly worded. I don't mind implementing IEnumerator or IEnumerable; I just thought the only way to do it was with the old Current/MoveNext/Reset methods.

Comment: I can't think of any reason this would be a good idea. Do I lack imagination? IEnumerator is not a complex or burdensome interface.

Comment: @Jodrell: Making things more simple isn't a good idea? Why?

Comment: Why do you thing that your collection should implement `IEnumerator<T>`?

Comment: Simpler is nearly always better but I can't imagine an answer simpler than an implementation of IEnumerator.

Comment: Hmmm... Sorry, guys, I thought it wasn't possible to implement IEnumerable using yield. Not implementing IEnumerator or IEnumerable wasn't really a requirement, I just wanted something simpler than the old Current/Reset/MoveNext which made me keep the state across calls, and can be quite cumbersome except for the simplest things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You won't *have* to implement `IEnumerable<T>` or `IEnumerable` to get `foreach` to work - but it would be a good idea to do so. It's very easy to do:

```
public class Foo : IEnumerable<Bar>
{
    public IEnumerator<Bar> GetEnumerator()
    {
        // Use yield return here, or 
        // just return Values.GetEnumerator()
    }

    // Explicit interface implementation for non-generic
    // interface; delegates to generic implementation.
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

The alternative which *doesn't* implement `IEnumerable<T>` would just call your `Values` property, but still providing a `GetEnumerator()` method:

```
public class Foo
{
    public IEnumerator<Bar> GetEnumerator()
    {
        // Use yield return here, or 
        // just return Values.GetEnumerator()
    }
]
```

While this will work, it means you won't be able to pass your collection to anything expecting an `IEnumerable<T>`, such as LINQ to Objects.

It's a little-known fact that `foreach` will work with any type supporting a `GetEnumerator()` method which returns a type with appropriate `MoveNext()` and `Current` members. This was really to allow strongly-typed collections before generics, where iterating over the collection wouldn't box value types etc. There's really no call for it now, IMO.

Comment: Thank you for the fast and complete answer. For some reason I thought yield could only be used to return an IEnumerable.

Comment: @Jaime: If you go to http://manning.com/skeet you can still get chapter 6 of the first edition of C# in Depth for free. That chapter is all about iterator blocks :)

Comment: @Jodrell: For chapter 8, you might as well get the second edition version (still free) from http://manning.com/skeet2/

Comment: @Jon: Thank you, those sample chapters look great. Are your books available in spanish?

Comment: @Jaime: Not as far as I'm aware, I'm afraid :(

Comment: @Jon: Thanks anyway, maybe I'll get it in english. I **really** need a .Net book.

Comment: @Jaime: It's probably worth being aware of the very limited scope of C# in Depth then. It's really *just* about the C# language, and assumes you know C# 1 already. You may be better off with C# 4 in a Nutshell, which covers the language and the core APIs.

Comment: @Jon: Thanks a lot for warning me, even if that could mean losing a sale ;-). I would like to know C# in depth, too. I'd say I know C#1 and 2. Of course I don't know everything, but, who does? (Ok, maybe someone who writes a book about it does, but that's not the point) So I'll try to take a glance at both and then decide. I really appreciate your advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could do somthing like this, but why? `IEnumerator` is already simple.

```
Interface MyEnumerator<T>
{
    public T GetNext();
}

public static class MyEnumeratorExtender
{
    public static void MyForeach<T>(this MyEnumerator<T> enumerator,
        Action<T> action)
    {
        T item = enumerator.GetNext();
        while (item != null)
        {
            action.Invoke(item);
            item = enumerator.GetNext();
        }
    }
}
```

I'd rather have the `in` keyword and I wouldn't want to rewrite linq.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. As stated above, I thought it wasn't possible to implement IEnumerator with yield, but now that I know better, I don't mind doing it :-)